# Adding borders and aesthetics to an Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

This may seem like a silly question but how can you add things like a boarder to multiple items like labels and text views ( i am not asking how to put a boarder on a single item).

Lets say i had a login screen with two labels user name and password and then 2 textviews with place holder text. How can i now put a boarder with rounded edges around all 4 items.

Would this be done by putting a view behind them if so the view has no boarder options, or would this be done with an imageView behind them. I would have thought Xcode had a tool to do things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the backing layer on `UIView`. Create a view to surround the elements you want a border around:

```
let containerView = UIView(frame: ...)
container.layer.borderWidth = 2
container.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
container.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

Comment: awesome Thanks, i thought this might have been the case. You would have thought there were tools to do this like dragging a boarder around objects. But thanks for clearing that up

Comment: There's very little 'styling' you can do from Storyboards/Interface Builder.  Ultimately you will have to drop down to code and modify things there, and you have total control over how things look.

Comment: Which is the way i would normally have done things but Xcode is so sleek with its Interface Builder you tend to want everything done for you haha Cheers buddy

Comment: That worked an absolute treat. Thanks for your time buddy

Answer (score 0):

Set tag value to each object. Now at run time you can get all subview of UIView.
Set corner radios, border width using QuartzCore Framework for all objects to which you want a border just by accessing them with unique tag values that you have assigned them initially.